# Password protect a magento cms page

Tags: javascript, jquery, password

I'm using nginx so `.htaccess` will not work.

I was hoping for it to be cookie based as well.

It's not a page that has to be terribly secure. The people who are visting it would not really even know how to access it if it was just a javascript or jquery password protect like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/LpdQm/16/

How would I add my custom block into this script?

`{{block type="cms/block" block_id="mggs"}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var password = 'password'
    var retVal = prompt("Enter your password : ", "your password here");
    if(retVal !== password)
    {
        location.assign('#');
    }
</script>
```